# tzset and daylight global variable interpretation in time.h

Tags: c, timezone, dst

In the time.h header for the daylight global variable it says:
 "This variable has a nonzero value if Daylight Saving Time rules apply. A nonzero value does not necessarily mean that Daylight Saving Time is now in effect; it means only that Daylight Saving Time is sometimes in effect."

Now I've noticed that in both Solaris 11.2 and Linux the "daylight" variable is being set to 1, even though my time-zone does not use daylight savings at all (Australia/Brisbane).

Sample code confirms this, if I run tzset and output the global variables we get: 
daylight = 1 tz[0] = [AEST] tz[1] = [AEDT] timezone = [-36000]

But by my understanding, daylight should be set to 0 since my zone does not have daylight savings at any time during the year.

I also noticed that the struct tm when set to current time returns a tm_isdst = 0, which is correct.

So why is the daylight variable set to 1?  Shouldn't it be set to 0?  Or am I misinterpreting this?

Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
void main()
{
  time_t t;
  struct tm     *tms = { 0 };
  tzset();
  time(&t);
  tms = localtime(&t);
  printf("date and time : %s",ctime(&t));
  printf("daylight = %d tz[0] = [%s] tz[1] = [%s] timezone = [%ld]\n", daylight, tzname[0], tzname[1], timezone);
  printf("tm_isdst = %d\n",tms->tm_isdst);
}
```

Output is:

```
date and time : Mon Nov 30 16:41:01 2015
daylight = 1 tz[0] = [AEST] tz[1] = [AEDT] timezone = [-36000]
tm_isdst = 0
```

Answer (score 6):

About the C Standard  `tm_isdst` member.

> The value of `tm_isdst` is positive if Daylight Saving Time is in effect, zero if Daylight Saving Time is not in effect, and negative if the information is not available. C11dr §7.27.1 4

This slightly differs from *nix specification about the *nix global variable  `daylight`.
`daylight` is not part of standard C.

---

[gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Time-Zone-Functions.html) reports

> Variable: int daylight
>   This variable has a nonzero value if Daylight Saving Time rules apply. A nonzero value does not necessarily mean that Daylight Saving Time is now in effect; it means only that Daylight Saving Time is **sometimes** in effect.

---

The `tm_isdst` refers to the `struct tm` timestamp.  It only means [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is in effect for that time-stamp.

`daylight != 0` implies DST is used sometimes in the timezone's timestamps.

As Australia/Brisbane once observed DST prior ([@Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33992918/2410359)) to 1972, having `daylight == 1` is reasonable as `daylight` implies DST was in effect for some periods of time for that timezone (likely since 1970).

OP's "... even though my time-zone does not use daylight savings at all" is not correct.

---

The following code shows that DST is used (at least the [timezone DB](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) thinks so) for some years since 1970 in "Australia/Brisbane".

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/time.h>

int main(void) {
  setenv("TZ", "Australia/Brisbane", 1);
  tzset();
  time_t now;
  time(&now);
  struct tm tm;
  int isdst = 42; // See Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy
  time_t t;
  for (t = 0; t < now; t += 3600) {
    tm = *localtime(&t);
    if (tm.tm_isdst != isdst) {
      printf("dst:%d %s", tm.tm_isdst, ctime(&t));
      isdst = tm.tm_isdst;
    }
  }
  printf("dst:%d %s", tm.tm_isdst, ctime(&t));
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
dst:0 Thu Jan  1 10:00:00 1970
dst:1 Sun Oct 31 03:00:00 1971
dst:0 Sun Feb 27 02:00:00 1972
dst:1 Sun Oct 29 03:00:00 1989
dst:0 Sun Mar  4 02:00:00 1990
dst:1 Sun Oct 28 03:00:00 1990
dst:0 Sun Mar  3 02:00:00 1991
dst:1 Sun Oct 27 03:00:00 1991
dst:0 Sun Mar  1 02:00:00 1992
dst:0 Tue Dec  1 16:00:00 2015
```

Comment: Thanks.  If you are right, then the documentation such as man tzset is misleading and incorrect when it says the daylight variable is "non-zero if there is a time during the year when daylight saving time applies".  Who can fix this?

Is there any other definitive information about it?

Comment: @Andrew Gray Significantly re-worked this answer to help distinguish between `daylight` and `tm_isdst` as my original answer seems to have convoluted the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I did understand your explanation of the difference, but I wonder why so much documentation incorrectly says that if daylight=1 then daylight savings is being used in that time-zone for that year, such as in the tzset man page.  It seems this is quite ambiguous.  But your code output is very helpful actually, thanks for that!

Comment: @Andrew Gray  I did not see nor conclude "if daylight=1 then daylight savings is being used in that time-zone for that _year_".  Perhaps you are reading something into the man pages that is not there?

Comment: man tzset specifically says if "daylight != 0 then there is a time during the YEAR when daylight saving time applies."  I think the plain reading of that indicates that if daylight=1 then during that YEAR there will be daylight savings, which as you point out is incorrect.  This incorrect documentation has caused a lot of confusion for both myself and other developers.  Another way to word the man page would be: daylight is non-zero if there is a time during the year when daylight saving time applies OR if there was a time in the past or a time in the future when daylight savings applies.

Comment: I found this in Redhat Bugzilla, reporting incorrectly setting daylight=1: [link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1077377).  If you are right, then this isn't a bug at all, if he is right then this is a OS bug and the man page is right.  What are your thoughts on the bug?

Comment: @Andrew Gray The idea `daylight=1` applies to a _year_ is problematic.  First of all what year? the current year?  If that were so, how would a zone in the southern hemisphere that was transition from/to using DST work?  Say that zone used DST for the last time in Oct 2015 to Mar 2016, but no longer in Oct 2016 onward.  What would `daylight` be then in 2016?  IOWs, the whole meaning `daylight` being 0 or not-0 has limited use.  As best I can see, it affirms the range of ` tzname[]` index being 0 to 0  or 0 to 1, but does not provide _any_ insight to what DST rules apply that year.

Comment: … OTOH using `daylight` to indicate is DST ever applied to that zone makes a _little_ more sense.  IMO, the C time functions are simple inadequate and beyond major improvement without significant overhaul.  To be open, I suspect @Andrew Gray that your present work exceeds my current expertise on the matter.

Answer (score 3):

Australia/Brisbane doesn't use daylight saving time *at the moment*, but it has in the past; look at the [`australasia`](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/australasia) file you'll see the few years where it has observed DST.

My interpretation of `daylight` is that it indicates whether that time zone has *ever* observed (or will ever obseve with the current rules) daylight savings. In other words, if this is 1 you need to be careful when performing date/time handling, whereas if it's 0 you can assume a constant UTC offset.

(It's not immediately clear to me whether a time zone which has never observed DST, but *has* shifted its standard UTC offset over time, would set `daylight` to 1 or not. I guess it would be strictly wrong to set it, but it would be practical to do so for the reasons above...)

Comment: Thanks.  The description of this variable is ambiguous, I haven't found a definitive answer yet.  

But I think you must be right.  I came across this because a large software vendor used this variable to determine if daylight savings should be observed at some point in the YEAR.  Thus, their software misidentifies a server in a Brisbane time zone as actually being in a Sydney time zone because "daylight=1".  This is why I titled this question as about interpretation.

I'd still like a definitive answer referencing some documentation if that's possible so I can take it back to the vendor.

Comment: man ctime shows this comment about daylight variable: ----
"The  localtime() function converts the calendar time timep to broken-time representation, expressed relative to the user's specified timezone.  The function acts as if it called tzset(3) and sets the external variables tzname with information about the current timezone, timezone with the difference between Coordinated Universal  Time (UTC)  and local standard time in seconds, and daylight to a non-zero value if daylight savings time rules apply during some part of the year."

---- This last bit contradicts us. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: @AndrewGray: As you say, it does sound like I'm wrong. Very odd API, in my view...

Comment: I think I'd need to look at the actual implementation to see whether that documentation is accurate or not. However, https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/localtime.c#L308 seems to back up my hypothesis - that does seem to be a "check through all of time" one. But I've never found that bit of C code easy to read, so I could be mistaken.

Comment: Thanks again.  I did a man tzset on Linux, it says this: ---- "In a System-V-like environment it will also set the variables timezone (seconds West of GMT) and daylight (0 if this  timezone  does  not have any daylight saving time rules, non-zero if there is a time during the year when daylight saving time applies)." ----  Again, this seems to contradict our hypothesis.  So confused.

Comment: Some websites say this: --- "extern int daylight;    /* nonzero if DST is ever in effect here */" --- also cf https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Time-Zone-Functions.html 
---- So I think your initial hypothesis is correct, I think the documentation is incorrect.

Comment: I wonder if there has been any confirmation of this behaviour.  I noticed someone posted a redhat bug about this behaviour, he obviously thought the documentation was correct and the implementation wrong.  Thoughts?

Comment: @AndrewGray: I would personally conclude that `daylight` shouldn't be used at all, as its meaning is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you consider what tzset() does - it installs a timezone definition. That is it interprets the contents of the TZ environment variable, loads a zoneinfo file or similar. One thing tzset() doesn't do is provide information based on any specific time, it doesn't for example look at the system clock or make assumptions about what the current year is. There are standard functions like gmtime(), localtime(), mktime() that deal with specific dates and times. tzset() just sets up the general framework for those functions to work and provides some vary basic information about the overall timezone definition in extern variables. tzset() doesn't tell you if there is daylight saving time now, because it doesn't know or care what "now" is. It can tell you if the overall timezone definition contains any information about daylight saving time, e.g. whether tz[1] is defined.

It seems that some of the documentation is outdated too, as it fails to specify clearly how tzset() presents more modern/complex timezone definitions in its extern variables, but understanding what tzset() does it is mostly clear what to expect from it.

The problem with "daylight" and "timezone" and some documentation is that they were created very early on when timezone definitions were nothing more than a TZ string, which has syntax that can specify names and time offsets and things like "DST starts 1st Sunday March, ends 3rd Sunday October". It contained no historical information, if the rules for a timezone changed then you just changed your TZ variable to implement the new rules. We now have things like the zoneinfo database with historical information, unfortunately the definition of tzset() hasn't keep up with this. It's fine internally: localtime() etc. will do the right thing when tzset() loads a complex timezone, but the simple extern variables can't always give an accurate summary. "daylight" isn't too bad: because tzset() doesn't consider any particular date/time, it is reasonable for it to set "daylight" if there is any daylight saving time defined anywhere in the timezone data, again essentially if tz[1] is defined. In principle pretty much anything in a timezone could change over the years including the timezone names, and the base timezone offset. This rarely happens but some real timezones have an unusual history, not least around the International Date Line.